# Cant index table - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I am trying to index a field called `category_id` but I keep getting an error saying `"MySQL server has gone away"` in phpmyadmin

About 100,000 rows of data.

So what is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to command line, try to index it from there not from phpmyadmin.